# How to run gulp tasks from a node script

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have a node script and I want to run a gulp task I have in the same script, how can I call it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('default', function (arg) {

});

// How do I call the task 'default'
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Eventually I found the way:

```
gulp.start('default');
```

Comment: Seems like this is not the official way (https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/505) but I have no idea how this should be done then?!

Comment: i got such error `c:\xyz\scripts\gulpfile.js:948
gulp.start('buildresources');
     ^

TypeError: gulp.start is not a function
`

Comment: @LeiYang It was removed. Read more in the link of Markus comment.

Answer (score 4):

Use an array in `start` method, in the case someone is looking for a way of running multiple tasks from search engines.

```
gulp.start( [ 'task1', 'task2' ] );
```