# Call a Gulp / Node task from a click in the browser?

Tags: node.js, gulp

Im using node to create a file on the file system. Ive wrapped it in a Gulp task so I can run it when I need too.

```
gulp.task('write', function () {
  fs.writeFile('./my-file.txt', 'This is my text', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});
```

How can I make the file be written when the user clicks a button in a webpage? I cant find out how to run Gulp / Node tasks from a user input in the browser.

Comment: I believe you need to make a POST-request to your web-server and handle it the way you want (run gulp task from Node.js)

Comment: Did you search on stack overflow? Is [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28493832/5452965) useful?

Comment: @codtex Yes I have searched. No I dont think that link is useful, I need to trigger from the browser not from node (which is on the server).

Comment: @Evans well then simply wrap the sample code `gulp.start('write');` in a **HTTP** request and it will be execute when such a request is fired e.g. `app.get('/trigger-gulp-write', (req, res) => { gulp.start('write'); });` that's it

Comment: @Evans Hi Enavs, Did u get any solution for this ? Even i am trying to trigger gulp task  on click of a button in Website to do some stuff